# Listing all logical volumes in LVM2 that are snapshots

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a logical volume that has snapshots where the lv name has the date in it.

I'm trying to locate that snapshot using lvs and i'm getting close but can't figure out how to list logical volumes that have an lv_attr of snapshot.

using the `lvs` command, I should be able to only list those LVs but I can't seem to get the selection part correct.

So far, I have

```
lvs -o lv_name,lv_attr  vg_mysql --separator='|' --noheadings
```

Which displays

> lv_mysql|owi-aos---
>   lv_mysql_snap_201506091622|swi-a-s---

Can i drill down further and get only the row that has the s as the attribute?

i tried adding `-S` but I think i'm using it incorrectly and can't find any good examples of it.

> lv_mysql_snap_20150609162221|**s**wi-a-s---

Or perhaps there is an easier way to get it?

thank you.

Comment: never mind. I think i am using the lv_attr incorrectly. lvs -S "lv_name=~[lv_mysql_snap_.*]" gets me what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my mistake.

I was trying

```
lvs -o lv_name,lv_attr  vg_mysql --separator='|' --noheadings -S "lv_attr=s"
```

but it should really be

```
lvs -o lv_name,lv_attr  vg_mysql --separator='|' --noheadings -S "lv_attr=~[^s.*]"
```

That will match the regex `[^s.*]` which shows a snapshot. If you wanted an exact match, you will need  `-S "lv_attr=swi-a-s---"`